# What if the .NET supported iso codes are not enough to discover the language/region

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I am working on a translation app.

The app should consider different regions of big countries like russia.

Therefore using iso639 is not enough thus I use additionally iso3166 together they

are: **ISO639-ISO3166** => "it-CH"

The native name would be "italiano" which I have to display to the translator guy.

.NET framework gives me 210 languages considering the regions with this code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
    var text = string.Format("\"{0} - {1}\",    \"{2}-{3}\"",
        region.EnglishName, culture.Parent.NativeName,
        culture.Parent.TwoLetterISOLanguageName,
           region.TwoLetterISORegionName);
    list.Add(text);
}
```

What if we have text to translate in a language for a certain region that is not supported by the .NET framework?

When I do:

```
var info = new CultureInfo("tt-RU");
string nativeName = info.Parent.NativeName;
```

I get the correct language.

But what if I pass a isocode combination that is not supported by the .NET framework? Then I can not display a language for the translator guy.

What would you do? Or do you think I should not plan that far?

Comment: do you have an example of such isocode?

Comment: Of the isocode that is not supported by .NET? No! because I do not know enough all countries not supported by .NET but I guess there exist more that 210 regions in the world. This is NOT a current Issue. I am just in the planning/concept phase!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple: Your piece of code doesn't list all the cultures which are supported by *the .Net framework*, because thesupported cultures depends on your OS.

The [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) documentation states that

> Windows versions or service packs can change the available cultures.

I guess, to answer your question, *What would you do? Or do you think I should not plan that far?*

If you need to work with languages which are not currently supported by your OS, you'll have to install a service pack that does support it, **OR** decide to leverage [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) in order to create a brand new culture and install on the computers that need it.

Bottom line is, for both cases: you don't need to plan that far ahead now, because if you create your own culture, it will be considered just as any other official culture on the computers that have it installed.

Comment: I thought the list of cultures are given that enumeration: .InstalledWin32Cultures and not SpecificCultures. Can you rephrase/explain that please in other words "because if you create your own culture, it will be considered just as any other official culture on the computers that have it installed."

Comment: Yes, sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. if you use CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) 

_The CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class enables you to create a custom culture that is completely new or that overrides a predefined culture._

You could then create a culture that isn't listed yet, and work with your translator by using it.

Comment: Ok so the admins could create this new culture by entering an iso639-iso3166 code in the UI. Is the new created culture respected by the CultureInfo.GetCultures() method?

Comment: Yes, admins can register a new unsupported culture (you will need admin rights). In fact, you could even create brand new exotic locales which don't exist in the iso639-iso3166 format. Once registered, these cultures can be used line any other. They should also be present in the returned array when calling CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx for details and examples